# How do create a pull request when I submit a react form under a private repo main branch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devops, github-api, cicd

Suppose I have a private repo whose name is **'sync-private-repo'**. when I submit a form in React JS then it will generate a markdown file. My requirement is when I submit the form then it will create a pull request with a markdown file under the **main** branch **'sync-private-repo'**. How can I achieve this?

Here is my code -

```
// app.js
const App = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    company: "",
    phone: "",
    website: "",
    visitors: 0,
    email: "",
    country: "",
    message: "",
    agree: false,
  });

  const handleInputChange = (fieldName, value) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [fieldName]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // You can handle the form submission logic here
    console.log("Form submitted with data:", formData);

    // Generate frontmatter and Markdown content based on form data
    const frontmatter = `
  ---
  title: Form Submission
  date: ${new Date().toISOString()}
  ---
  
  `;

    // Generate Markdown content based on form data
    const markdownContent = `${frontmatter}
     # Form Submission
     
     **First Name:** ${formData.first_name}
     **Last Name:** ${formData.last_name}
     **Company:** ${formData.company}
     **Website:** ${formData.website}
     **Visitors:** ${formData.visitors}
     **Country:** ${formData.country}
     **Message:** ${formData.message}
     **Agree:** ${formData.agree.toString()}
     `;

    // // Create a Blob from the Markdown content
    // const blob = new Blob([markdownContent], { type: "text/markdown" });

    // // Create a link element
    // const link = document.createElement("a");
    // link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // link.download = "form_submission.md";

    // // Append the link to the document and trigger the download
    // document.body.appendChild(link);
    // link.click();

    // // Remove the link from the document
    // document.body.removeChild(link);

    // Create a Blob from the Markdown content
    const blob = new Blob([markdownContent], { type: "text/markdown" });

    // Create FormData object and append the file
    const formDataObj = new FormData();
    formDataObj.append("file", blob, "form_submission.md");

    // Replace 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' with your actual GitHub personal access token
    const accessToken = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";
    const owner = "YOUR_OWNER_NAME"; // Replace with the owner of the target repository
    const repo = "YOUR_PRIVATE_REPO"; // Replace with the name of the target repository

    try {
      // Step 1: Create a new branch
      const branchResponse = await fetch(
        `https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/git/refs`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            ref: "refs/heads/new-branch-name", // Replace with a unique branch name
            sha: "main", // Replace with the branch you want to base the new branch on
          }),
        }
      );

      const branchData = await branchResponse.json();

      console.log("branchData----->", branchData);

      // Step 2: Upload the file to the new branch
      const uploadResponse = await fetch(
        `https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/contents/form_submission.md`,
        {
          method: "PUT",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            message: "Add form_submission.md",
            branch: "new-branch-name", // Replace with the branch name you created
            content: blob,
          }),
        }
      );

      const uploadData = await uploadResponse.json();

      console.log("uploadData----->", uploadData);

      // // Step 3: Create a pull request
      const pullRequestResponse = await fetch(
        `https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/pulls`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            title: "Form Submission",
            head: "new-branch-name", // Replace with the branch name you created
            base: "main", // Replace with the branch you want to merge into
          }),
        }
      );

      const pullRequestData = await pullRequestResponse.json();

      console.log("Pull request created:", pullRequestData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating pull request:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className="container mx-auto flex py-24 bg-slate-100">
      <div className="w-2/4 px-8">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="grid gap-6 mb-6 md:grid-cols-2">
            <div>
              <label
                htmlFor="first_name"
                className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
              >
                First name
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="first_name"
                className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"
                placeholder="John"
                required
                onChange={(e) =>
                  handleInputChange("first_name", e.target.value)
                }
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label
                htmlFor="last_name"
                className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
              >
                Last name
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="last_name"
                className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"
                placeholder="Doe"
                required
                onChange={(e) => handleInputChange("last_name", e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label
                htmlFor="company"
                className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
              >
                Company
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="company"
                className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"
                placeholder="Proteinreport"
                required
                onChange={(e) => handleInputChange("company", e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label
                htmlFor="phone"
                className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
              >
                Phone number
              </label>
              <input
                type="tel"
                id="phone"
                className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"
                placeholder="123-45-678"
                required
                onChange={(e) => handleInputChange("phone", e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label
                htmlFor="website"
                className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
              >
                Website URL
              </label>
              <input
                type="url"
                id="website"
                className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"
                placeholder="proteinreport.com"
                required
                onChange={(e) => handleInputChange("website", e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label
                htmlFor="visitors"
                className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
              >
                Unique visitors (per month)
              </label>
              <input
                type="number"
                id="visitors"
                className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"
                placeholder=""
                required
                onChange={(e) =>
                  handleInputChange("visitors", e.target.value.toString())
                }
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="mb-6">
            <label
              htmlFor="email"
              className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
            >
              Email address
            </label>
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"
              placeholder="john.doe@company.com"
              required
              onChange={(e) => handleInputChange("email", e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="mb-6">
            <label className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
              Select your country:
            </label>
            <select
              id="countries"
              value={formData.selectField}
              onChange={(e) => handleInputChange("country", e.target.value)}
              className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"
            >
              <option value="usa">United States</option>
              <option value="canada">Canada</option>
              <option value="france">France</option>
              <option value="germany">Germany</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className="mb-6">
            <label
              htmlFor="message"
              className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
            >
              Your message
            </label>
            <textarea
              id="message"
              rows="4"
              required
              className="block p-2.5 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500"
              placeholder="Write your thoughts here..."
              onChange={(e) => handleInputChange("message", e.target.value)}
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-start mb-6">
            <div className="flex items-center h-5">
              <input
                id="remember"
                type="checkbox"
                value=""
                className="w-4 h-4 border border-gray-300 rounded bg-gray-50 focus:ring-3 focus:ring-blue-300"
                required
                onChange={() => handleInputChange("agree", !formData.agree)}
              />
            </div>
            <label
              htmlFor="remember"
              className="ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
            >
              I agree with the{" "}
              <a href="#" className="text-blue-600 hover:underline">
                terms and conditions
              </a>
              .
            </label>
          </div>
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm w-full sm:w-auto px-5 py-2.5 text-center"
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div className="w-2/4 px-8">
        <h2 className="text-4xl font-extrabold">Form Preview</h2>
        <br />
        <p className="text-2xl text-gray-900 mb-4">
          First Name: {formData.first_name}
        </p>
        <p className="text-2xl text-gray-900 mb-4">
          Last Name: {formData.last_name}
        </p>
        <p className="text-2xl text-gray-900 mb-4">
          Company: {formData.company}
        </p>
        <p className="text-2xl text-gray-900 mb-4">Phone: {formData.phone}</p>
        <p className="text-2xl text-gray-900 mb-4">
          Website: {formData.website}
        </p>
        <p className="text-2xl text-gray-900 mb-4">
          Visitors: {formData.visitors.toString()}
        </p>
        <p className="text-2xl text-gray-900 mb-4">Email: {formData.email}</p>
        <p className="text-2xl text-gray-900 mb-4">
          Country: {formData.country}
        </p>
        <p className="text-2xl text-gray-900 mb-4">
          Message: {formData.message}
        </p>
        <p className="text-2xl text-gray-900 mb-4">
          Agree: {formData.agree.toString()}
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

But it show this error?

[image]